# suddenly new external harddrive not detected in windows, Ubuntu machines

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, disk-space, hard-drive-recovery

I bought new external harddrive `Toshiba Canvio Ready 1TB USB 3.2 Gen 1 External Portable Hard Drive (HDTP310AK3AA, Black)`
and copied all data from my computer to external harddrive.

It fills about 900+ gb of space.

After two days when i insert(windows machine) external harddrive, its not showing up. I checked disk management, there is no empty space or new drive showing up.
checked driver management, there also no driver controller showing up, except only one default driver.

I feel like external harddrive slightly vibrating(can hear fan sound too) when inserted in usb port(3.0,2.0) and its blue light not turned on(i think blue light comes only when copying or pasting files).

I inserted to linux laptop and checked there also no drive showing up even in gparted, disks.

what to do?

Comment: Send it back for a new one, or a refund.